# Make lines of radar chart round in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

I have code for a radar chart below created in the plotly package in R. The lines are straight from point to point but I would like to make them curved. I'm trying to read documentation to plotly but having trouble interpreting.

This is the code I have:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    r = c(1,3,2,4,1),
    theta = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
    fill = 'toself',
    line = list(c(shape = "spline"))
) 
fig %>%
    layout(
        polar = list(
            radialaxis = list(
                visible = T,
                range = c(0,4)
            )
        ),
        showlegend = F
    )
```

[image]

I would like the lines to be curved at the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to enclose the shape call as vector.

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  mode = "lines+markers",
  r = c(1,3,2,4,1, 1),
  theta = c("A","B","C","D","E", "A"),
  fill = 'toself',
  line = list(shape = 'spline')
) 
fig %>%
  layout(
    polar = list(
      radialaxis = list(
        visible = T,
        range = c(0,4)
      )
    ),
    showlegend = F
  )
```

[image]

To change the colors of the background and the grid lines:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  mode = "lines+markers",
  r = c(1,3,2,4,1, 1),
  theta = c("A","B","C","D","E", "A"),
  fill = 'toself',
  line = list(shape = 'spline')
) 
fig %>%
  layout(
    polar = list(
      bgcolor = "yellow",
      radialaxis = list(
        visible = T,
        range = c(0,4),
        gridcolor = "blue",
        linecolor = "red"),
      angularaxis = list(
        linecolor = "darkgreen")
    ),
    showlegend = F

  )
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to change the color of the background (color of circle) and the color of the grid lines as well? I can't find how to change the background color in the reference.

Comment: Thanks so much! Forcing to read the documentation. It's making more sense now :)